# How to make promise wait until end of loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around promises and struggling a little bit.

This is the code:

```
// For Every row.
var prom = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        existing_rows.forEach ((item,index) => {
            console.log("onto index: " + index);
            //We just need to set item[2]! 
            if (item[1].indexOf('%')===-1) {
                //Cool no percentage sign.
                translateClient.translate(item[1], 'th')
                    .then((results) => {
                        const translation = results[0];
                        console.log("translation is: " + translation);
                        item[2] = translation;
                     });
            }
        })

        resolve("Stuff worked!");
    })

prom.then(
    (result) => {
        //Cool that's finished.
        console.log("done!")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(existing_rows));
    }

)
```

existing_rows is just an array I'm looking at with some stuff to translate using the google api. I want the translations to all be placed in the existing_rows array before I log it in the prom.then block.

At the moment, the output is in this order:

```
onto index 0
onto index ..
onto index 8

done!
logs the array without the translations

translation is: ...... x 8
```

Thanks

Comment: Suggest you use `Promise.all` + `Array#map` instead of `new Promise` + `Array#forEach`

Comment: And create a new promise for each 'iteration' within the map?

Comment: Ah I'll check out your answer :P

Comment: There are a number of questions about this already on the site. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28134271/215552, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17217736/215552, http://stackoverflow.com/q/31947933/215552...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I agree those questions seem to be similar, the interesting thing is, none of the accepted answers would be usable for this code

Comment: I found both of those but couldn't really apply them to my case.. @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, there's more to a duplicate than the accepted answer, but searching on the title came up with http://stackoverflow.com/q/31426740/215552 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/37213783/215552, which are both pretty close. Note that I didn't vote to close as a duplicate, I'm just saying that this question, and questions like it, have been asked many times, and searching first is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Promise.all and Array#map instead of new Promise and Array#forEach

```
var prom = Promise.all(existing_rows.map((item, index) => {
        console.log("onto index: " + index);
        //We just need to set item[2]! 
        if (item[1].indexOf('%') === -1) {
            //Cool no percentage sign.
            return translateClient.translate(item[1], 'th')
                .then((results) => {
                    const translation = results[0];
                    console.log("translation is: " + translation);
                    item[2] = translation;
                });
        }
        // see note 1
    })
);
prom.then(
    (result) => {
        //Cool that's finished.
        console.log("done!")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(existing_rows));
    }
)
```

[1] there is no return value here, but that's OK, that's the equivalent of `return undefined` and `Promise.all` works fine with an array of non-Promises + Promises ...

Answer (score 0):

Roughly, like this:

```
// For Every row.
Promise.all(existing_rows.map((item, index) => {
      console.log("onto index: " + index);
      // We just need to set item[2]! 
      if (item[1].indexOf('%')===-1) {
          // Cool no percentage sign.
          return translateClient.translate(item[1], 'th')
              .then((results) => {
                  const translation = results[0];
                  console.log("translation is: " + translation);
                  item[2] = translation;
              });
      }
}))
.then(result => {
    // Cool that's finished.
    console.log("done!")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(existing_rows));      
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Jaromanda commented first suggesting the same thing.