# for loop, element binding

Tags: javascript, loops, binding

i have a question about a foor loop.
Why is my output every time "C" ?

```js
function Dummy(){}

Dummy.prototype.a = function(){ console.log("Hello from A"); };
Dummy.prototype.b = function(){ console.log("Hello from B"); };
Dummy.prototype.c = function(){ console.log("Hello from C"); };

function hooks(obj){
 for(method in obj){
    original = obj[method];
   obj[method] = function(){
     console.log("Overrid %s", method);
      original();
    };
  }
}

var instance = new Dummy();
hooks(instance);

instance.a();
instance.b();
instance.c();
```

I would to create an hookable middleware

Comment: Found a solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7269313/5781499
But can anyone explain why ?, thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution code:
The reason of this is that when you assign the function to 'original' variable it will always reference the last assignment because the 'original' variable is declared in global scope.

```
function Dummy(){}

Dummy.prototype.a = function(){ console.log("Hello from A"); };
Dummy.prototype.b = function(){ console.log("Hello from B"); };
Dummy.prototype.c = function(){ console.log("Hello from C"); };

function hooks(obj){
    for(method in obj){
        (function(original, method) {

            obj[method] = function(){
                console.log("Overrid %s", method);
                original();
            };
        })(obj[method], method)
    }
}

var instance = new Dummy();
hooks(instance);

instance.a();
instance.b();
instance.c();
```

Comment: While this works, the answer from @MackCope is much simpler: just add `let`s.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure to declare your variables. "method" and "original" were never declared. See the working example below:

```js
function Dummy(){}

Dummy.prototype.a = function(){ console.log("Hello from A"); };
Dummy.prototype.b = function(){ console.log("Hello from B"); };
Dummy.prototype.c = function(){ console.log("Hello from C"); };

function hooks(obj){
 for(let method in obj){
    let original = obj[method];
   obj[method] = function(){
     console.log("Overrid %s", method);
      original();
    };
  }
}

var instance = new Dummy();
hooks(instance);

instance.a();
instance.b();
instance.c();
```

Comment: Thank you, i have forgett this in my example.
My comment in the post above is what i needed.